# php some regex without end

Tags: php

I am trying to learn regex and have a string, I want the beginning to be (not including)

```
.com/
```

and the end to be (not including)

```
">[tomato
```

I can make the basic regex ok, but it keeps including the tomato part in it, instead of ending just before it.  So if I have

```
'sdf98uj3.com/sdjkh.sdf./sdf.sdf">[tomatoiosdf8uj3'
```

, then I want to return:

```
sdjkh.sdf./sdf.sdf
```

I am using preg_match in php.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you are actually parsing URLs or HTML, regexes are not the best way to go (though they are pretty nifty for a lot of things and well worth learning).  For URLs have a look at the PHP manual under parse_url or pathinfo. For HTML, have a look at SimpleXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('~\.com/(.*?)">\[tomato~', $str, $match);
```

`$match[1]` contains your string. The `(.*?)` is a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that captures every character between `.com/` and `">[tomato`.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good start for learning regular expressions.

---

Could also be solved without regex, using `strpos`[*<sup>(docs)</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), `strrpos`[*<sup>(docs)</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and `substr`[*<sup>(docs)</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$start = strpos($str, '.com/');
$end = strrpos($str, '">[tomato'); // or strpos to find the first occurance
$sub = substr($str, $start, $end-$start);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/(.*?)\.com/(.*?)">\[tomato(.*)/', $text, $matches);

echo $matches[2];
```